# azure devops release pipeline , bulk edit

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

```
$Organization = "y"
$Project = "x"
$DefinitionID = "81"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$Organization/$Project/_apis/build/definitions/$DefinitionID?api-version=6.0"

Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$pipeline.variables.v1030.value = "xyz"

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'v1030' is updated to" 
$updatedef.variables.v1030.value
```

error:

```
2022-03-17T13:05:24.9981259Z Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Build pipeline 
2022-03-17T13:05:24.9982421Z 81 was not found.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Definition
2022-03-17T13:05:24.9982939Z NotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"Definitio
2022-03-17T13:05:24.9983313Z nNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Hi I get this error in Logs,
I think I can not find the release pipeline number
The $ DefinitionID

I want to do it on 100 releases pipelines I'll wrap it with 'for' later, but first I want to see I can do on one

Comment: The following problem is not consistent with your symptom, but it is a problem with your code: `"...$DefinitionID?api-version=6.0"` must be `"...${DefinitionID}?api-version=6.0"` in order for `$DefinitionID` to be expanded as intended - otherwise, the `?` character is considered _part of the variable name_. [GitHub issue #11379](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11379) discusses this counterintuitive behavior and suggests it be changed.